# Django авторизация по email (вместо username)

Tags: django, users, аутентификация

Сделал вход сайт почти по мануалу, но теперь надо переделать поле username на email, а еще лучше на оба сразу в зависимости о того, что вводит пользователь.
Итак, по views.py:

```
def do_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request=request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            try:
                user=authenticate(username=User.objects.get(email=username), password=password)
            except:
                user=authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                messages.info(request, f"You are now logged in as {username}")
                return redirect('form/')
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request = request, template_name = "dologin.html", context={"form":form})
```

Функция она принимает только username, а на емэил дает ошибку ввода. Не понимаю, может я совсем не в том направлении пишу.

Comment: Уберите except и прочитайте, что за ошибка возникает

Comment: если ввожу мэил, то Invalid username or password. если логин, то AuthenticationForm' object has no attribute 'get'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопросами аутентификации должен заниматься [бэкенд аутентификации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#authentication-backends), а не *представление* логина.

**auth.py**

```
class EmailAuthBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        if '@' in username:
            kwargs = {'email': username}
        else:
            kwargs = {'username': username}

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(**kwargs)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
            else:
                return None
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

**settings.py**

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'someapp.auth.EmailAuthBackend',
]
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/login/', LoginView.as_view()),
]
```

или даже

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

Comment: спасибо! заработало, но пришлось добавить реквест в модель def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):

Comment: Согласно исходному коду надо писать def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs). Без добавления **kwargs у меня не работало

Comment: @Artiom три года прошло, API изменилось.